# Summarise tree (nested object) at a given level

Tags: javascript, recursion, javascript-objects

I have a tree of nested objects (3 levels, representing building, floor, room). Leaf nodes contain the room area. I would like to summarise that area at a given level (provided dynamically), without mutating the source data.

```
const data = {
  building1: {
    floor1: {
      room1: {
        area: 0.1,
      },
      room2: {
        area: 0.2,
      }
    },
    floor2: {
      room1: {
        area: 0.3,
      },
      room2: {
        area: 0.4,
      }
    }
  },
  building2: {
    floor1: {
      room1: {
        area: 0.15,
      },
      room2: {
        area: 0.25,
      }
    },
    floor2: {
      room1: {
        area: 0.35,
      },
      room2: {
        area: 0.45,
      }
    }
  },
  level: 3
};
```

For example I need a level 1 (building-level) summary to return a new object that looks like this:

```
{
  building1: {
      area: 1
  },
  building2: {
      area: 1.2
  }
}
```

And I'd like to be able to get a level 2 summary that looks like this:

```
{
  building1: {
    floor1: {
      area: 0.3
    },
    floor2: {
      area: 0.7
    }
  },
  building2: {
    floor1: {
      area: 0.4
    },
    floor2: {
      area: 0.8
    }
  }
}
```

Accumulation is just by simple arithmetic sum. I can get the summary (combined area) of any node in the tree, but am unsure how to clone the source data and replace the data at the desired level with the summary.

```
const addAreas = (op1, op2) => ({
  area: op1.area + op2.area
})

const traverseNodeToArea = node => {
  return Object.entries(node).map(([key, val]) =>
    val.hasOwnProperty('area')
      ? val
      : traverseNodeToArea (val)
  ).reduce(addAreas,{
    area: 0
  });
};
```

Happy to use lodash if that helps. I'm sure there must be an easy solution to this but I just can't see it.

(`traverseNodeToArea` is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38382099/629287))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a level counter and if the level is zero, get the sum of remaining nested areas.

```js
function getSummary(object, level) {
    const getSumOfArea = object => Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => r + (k === 'area' ? v : getSumOfArea(v)), 0);

    if (!object || typeof object !== 'object')
        return object;

    if (level)
        return Object.assign(...Object.entries(object).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: getSummary(v, level - 1) })));

    return { area: getSumOfArea(object) };
}

const data = { building1: { floor1: { room1: { area: 0.1, }, room2: { area: 0.2, } }, floor2: { room1: { area: 0.3, }, room2: { area: 0.4, } } }, building2: { floor1: { room1: { area: 0.15, }, room2: { area: 0.25, } }, floor2: { room1: { area: 0.35, }, room2: { area: 0.45, } } }, level: 3 };

console.log(getSummary(data, 0));
console.log(getSummary(data, 1));
console.log(getSummary(data, 2));
console.log(getSummary(data, 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```